# Set of all real numbers with a '$2$' in their decimal expansion

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, infinite-groups

It is a common question in an elementary probability or combinatorics class to ask "How many integers between $1$ and $10^k$ have at least one '$2$' in their decimal expansion?" This result can then be generalized further, and analyzed as $k$ approaches infinity

However, I'm curious about something slightly different; rather than the set of all integers with a '$2$' in their decimal expansion, I want to consider the set of all real numbers with a '$2$' in their decimal expansion. More specifically, I have the following questions:

1) Which has greater cardinality: the set of all real numbers with a '$2$' in their decimal expansion (which we will denote by $S$), or the set of all real numbers without a '$2$' in their decimal expansion (ie $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$)?

2) In comparing the above sets, $S$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$, by 'how much' is one set's size greater than the other? I realize this is a poorly phrased question, and am not really looking for a formal answer. Anything that gives some general intuition would be much appreciated.

For question 1, I am leaning towards thinking that the latter set, of all real numbers without a '$2$' in their decimal expansion, would be larger. To show this, I've tried using alternative bases and formulating some sort of mapping between the sets, to no avail. I also thought about simplifying the problem to just include numbers in the set $[0, 1]$, and then generalizing for $\mathbb{R}$. However, I haven't found anything by doing this either. I haven't yet attempted the second question, although I think the way I approach the first will largely dictate the answer here.

I'd appreciate any and all help with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: It should be an easy application of the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem that those two sets each have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ hence they have the same cardinality as each other. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem

Comment: Also, cardinality questions are not the same as probability questions. It is an entirely different issue to ask what is the probability that a real number has (or has not) a $2$ in its decimal expansion; here "probability" can be interpreted in the sense of Lebesgue measure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure

Comment: We can set up a one-to-one mapping from $S$ to $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$, simply by replacing every '2' in the decimal expansion of $x \in S$ with a '0' (or some other digit.)  So the cardinality of $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ cannot be larger than the cardinality of $S$.

Answer (score 7):

The **cardinalities** are the same, namely the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ itself. We can form injections from $(0,1)$ into either $(0,1)\cap S$ or $(0,1)\setminus S$ by the rules

- $x\mapsto 0.2 + \frac1{10}x$, or
- Replace all digits `2` in the decimal expansion by `37` and all (original) digits `3` by `35`.

---

By **Lebesgue measure**, however, the difference is dramatic: $(0,1)\cap S$ has measure $1$ whereas $\mathbb R\setminus S$ has measure $0$. In other words, **almost all** real numbers (and this is a technical term) have a `2` somewhere in their decimal expansion.

We can see this by writing

$$ \mathbb (0,1)\setminus S =
\bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{ x\in(0,1)\mid \text{the $n$th decimal of $x$ is not $2$}\} $$
This is the limit for $k\to\infty$ of
$$ \bigcap_{n=1}^k \{ x\in(0,1)\mid \text{the $n$th decimal of $x$ is not $2$}\} $$
whose measure is $0.9^k$ -- each time we exclude `2` from another position, we lose $\frac1{10}$ of the numbers we have left. And $0.9^k\to 0$ for $k\to\infty$. So the measure of $(0,1)\setminus S$ is $0$, and similarly for every other unit interval.

---

In fact, it is known that *almost all* real numbers are **normal** in base 10 (or any other base), and therefore have *infinitely many* 2s in their decimal expansion.